# PWA - Adding page to homescreen on IOS blocks access to camera

Tags: reactjs, camera, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia

I've been working on a PWA app using React Js. It's basically a Qr code scanner, so I need to access the camera.

First thing I do to make sure the browser supports camera is to check 'getUserMedia'
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

So far I am able to access the camera just fine, except when I try to access it using chrome on IOS.

The problem was that when I saved the app on my Homescreen and opened it, the app couldn't acceess the camera. It failed exactly when it tests `getUserMedia`.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I suspect (but I'm not sure) you'll need to serve the page containing the gUM call directly from an https:// server and not from the pwa service worker cache. iOS gUM is really tight on security. Please, if you figure it out answer your own question so we can all get the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has been solved in IOS 13.